# Is this a T track garage door bottom seal retainer?

Tags: garage-door

I’m replacing my garage door bottom seal and while it looks like a T-track to me, it’s also just misshapen enough that I’m second guessing myself.

[Here’s a couple photos of it](https://imgur.com/a/WIamhLd). Can anyone confirm it’s a T track and not something else?

Comment: it doe look like T-track